# Replace entire char array with different char

Tags: java, arrays, char

I'm very new to programming and I've spent some time looking for a way to do this that I can understand. I'm making a hangman game in java, it's all text based, and I've got almost the entire thing done. All I need is to replace a character array that holds the value of a random word to be replaced with dashes. So if the word was "java" I need to change that character array to "----". Since the word is chosen at random from a list, I have to find a way to use the length of the word to apply those dashes, but I'm not sure how.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you done for coding so far??

Comment: So you have to create an array of a given length, loop over all the indices ofthe array, and set the value for each index to '-'. That doesn't seem so hard. What have you tried? Have you read the Java tutorial about arrays? Have you learnt loops?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].

Comment: I haven't done a lot as far as coding goes, mostly just using the different types of variables. I'm in CS 1400 which is intro to Java, so it's all very basic level stuff.

Comment: Well now you got plenty of examples on how to do what you asked for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an example based on what you have provided so far with java and ----:

```
    public class Program {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        String value = "java";
        char[] array = value.toCharArray();

        // Convert string to a char array.
        for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
        {
              array[i] = '-';
        }
        // Loop over chars in the array.
        for (char c : array) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for this, I cackled like a madman when it worked!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to replace all the characters by '_' would be :

```
char[] charArray = {'W','O','R','D'};
Arrays.fill(charArray, '_');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, a few things that may be helpful in solving this task:

1. If you have a String you can easily get the length of that String like this:

   ```
   String word = "java";
   int lengthOfWord = word.length();
   ```
2. You can easily edit the contents of an array by accessing the individual elements:

   ```
   char[] array = new char[4];
   array[0] = '-';
   array[1] = '_';
   array[2] = '-';
   array[3] = '_';
   ```
3. If you want to do something repeatedly and know how often you want to do that, using a `for`-loop is often a great idea. And you can use the counter within the loop. So for example:

   ```
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       sum += i;
   }
   ```

So, combine those pieces of information and you can replace every element of that array. :-)

Comment: Using [`Arrays.fill(charArray, '-')`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-char:A-char-) might be simpler.

Comment: @MarekCiesla It would be, yes. But before learning the shortcut it would probably be a good idea to understand the above concepts.